# Growing Ipomea near mid-sized conifer?

Tags: plant-recommendations, conifers, climbers

Is it possible, and is it wise if it is possible, to grow [Ipomea tricolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_tricolor) 'Heavenly Blue' so that it protrudes through mid-sized (9m/30ft) conifers?

I think it could be an interesting aesthetic effect - blue-yellow flowers hanging from greenish conifer.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is being able to plant it close enough to your trees so that it can climb up them.  Where you are this plant is only an annual, as it is in the UK, and reaches about 2.5 metres in a good year, but you can't plant too close to the roots of the trees because it will likely be deprived of both water and nutrients, you'd need to plant at least two feet away, in front of the trees. You could plant in a pot and stand near the trees, but it won't get so large as it would in the ground, and given the height of your trees, may well look a little lost amongst them.

The other problem is, this plant is a twiner, and many conifers are really quite difficult for such a plant to twine around - petiole or tendril climbers such as clematis have an easier time of it in that regard. You'd probably need to provide long canes for the stems to twine around, which I'm sure isn't the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Ipomea is meant for hanging pots and standing large pots to DROOP over the side.  The are not 'climbers' Great answer, Bamboo!!

Comment: @stormy They are always grown in the UK as climbers, if we bother at all...I've never seen one trailing apart from the one with almost black  foliage which does not flower and remains small, which is usually planted in tubs and pots

Comment: Honest?  I used Ipomea for my pots and hanging baskets for which we charged inhuman bucks!  $250 per 14 to 16" hanging basket.  $2000 for 3 to 4' sand cast pots with 2 to 3' diameters.  Ipomea is not a climber.  I've used the limes, the blacks, the reds...all are trailing, not climbing.  They flow OVER the edges filling in that particular dimension.  Like, Asparagus Fern or trailing petunia.  Sure they might climb if they aren't getting enough light but I've not seen this aspect or I would have used it to my benefit, grins!!

Comment: All plants flower, right?  Just some are inconspicuous? Are they making plants that DON'T flower on purpose?

Comment: This is the foliage only one http://www.brooksidenursery.co.uk/ipomoea-black-tone--5-large-plug-plants-84557-p.html - I've never seen it flower, but it dies when autumn comes here

Comment: It is an annual in my world but somehow I have this hard and fast rule in my head from somewhere; All Plants Flower.  I've a headache and getting lazy.  Is this wrong?  Right?  Good night!

Comment: Its an annual here; it does flower, but needs a very warm climate (tropical) to do so apparently

Comment: I feel much better.  Whew!  I've grown these so much yet I've never seen them 'climb' .  I found a new 'word'...they are called 'spillers'...ha ha, I am serious, spillers.Spill over the edge.

Comment: Interestingly, the black form of Ipomea does not climb... its not a twiner, unlike Ipomea Heavenly Blue and the 'tricolor' range - they all climb by twining